# React Native Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, function, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a simple function that register users in firebase and save data in cloud firestore

But I am getting this error:

> [TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function]

Can anyone help my find where is located the error?

function below:

```
const handleSignUp = useCallback(
    async data => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        const auth = await authFB().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          data.email,
          data.password,
        );

        const db = firestore();

        const firstName = data.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        const lastName = data.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');

        await db
          .collection('Providers')
          .doc(auth.user.uid)
          .set({
            id: auth.user.uid,
            name: {
              first: firstName,
              last: lastName,
            },
            email: data.email,
            createdAt: firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
            address: {
              position: firestore.GeoPoint(
                coordinates.latitude,
                coordinates.longitude,
              ),
            },
          })
          .then(() => {
            navigation.reset({
              routes: [{ name: 'SignIn' }],
              index: 0,
            });
          });

        setLoading(false);

        Alert.alert(
          'Cadastro realizado com sucesso!',
          'Você já pode fazer login na aplicação.',
        );
      } catch (err) {
          setLoading(false);
      }
    },
    [coordinates],
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familiar with the Firestore API, but most likely you just need the `new` keyword where you're creating a GeoPoint:

```
position: new firestore.GeoPoint(
    coordinates.latitude,
    coordinates.longitude,
),
```